# How to fix a point on the surface of a 3D model created by texture mapping in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Let's see an image first:

[image]

The model in the image is create by texture mapping. I want to have a mouse clicked on the screen, then I want to place a fixed point on the surface of the model. What's more, as the model rotates, the fixed point is still on the surface of the model.

My question is:

1. How can I place the fixed point on the surface of the model?
2. How can I get the coordinate (x, y, z) of the fixed point?

My thought is as follows:

1. use gluUnproject function to get two points when I have the mouse clicked on the screen. One point is on the near clip plane and another is on the far one.
2. concatenate the two points to form a line.
3. iterate points on the line of step 2 and use glReadPixels to get the pixel value of the iterated points. If the the values jump from zero to nonzero or jump from nonzero to zero(the pixel value of background is zero), the surface points are found.

This is my thought. But it seems that it does not work!!! Can anyone give me some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Well basically the best approach is using physics ( Or check if there is a another simple raytracer ) and use the raycast function there. Then you get a point where you clicked. However you need to apply the inverse matrices ( projection view model ) to make this work.

Comment: You should always link to the previous question that you already asked. [How to access the pixel data along z direction in 3D model created by texture in OpenGL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289885), otherwise people that try to help you will ask the same question or will give the same answers.

Comment: @t.niese, Thank you for your advice. I will take an attention on it. Whatis more, can you tell me your thought about my questions? Thank you!

Comment: @Felix K, Sorry, I do not understand your answer because I am new to OpenGL. Can you tell me more detail about your thought? Which functions should I use to handle my questions? I hope you can tell me more detail. Thank you!

Comment: In short, at a lower level OpenGL works with Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC) in the range [-1,1].  If you have the x and y pixels coords you can easily map those to NDC coords from your window/viewport dimensions.  Likewise the z NDC can be read from the depth buffer.  Having (x,y,z) in NDC you can then use the inverse of your transformation matrix to map that back to model coordinates.  Probably.

Comment: There is no "build-in" function to do this properly. You need to use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_engine or do raycasting manually.

Comment: what you need is called "decals" .Google for it.You have tons of examples in the web.

Comment: @FelixK.: A physics engine is not going to help, because OP is not dealing with a solid here.

Comment: @Felix K,@datenwolf,  Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

> The model in the image is create by texture mapping.

No, it's not. First and foremost there is no model at all. What you have there is a 3D dataset of voxels and then you have a volume rasterizer that "shoots" rays through the dataset, integrates them up and for each ray produces a color and opacity value.

This process **is not**(!!!) texture mapping. Texture mapping is when you draw a "solid" primitive and for each fragment (a fragment is what eventually becomes a pixel) determines a *single* location in the texture data set and samples it. *But a volume raycaster as you have it there performs a whole ray integration effectively sampling many voxels from the whole dataset into a single pixel.* That's a completely different way of creating a color-opacity value.

> My question is:
>
> - How can I place the fixed point on the surface of the model?

You can't because the dataset you have there does not have a "fixed" surface point. You have to define *some* segmentation operation that decides which position along the ray constitutes as *"this is the surface"*. The simple most method would be using a threshold cutoff function.

> - How can I get the coordinate (x, y, z) of the fixed point?

Your best bet would be modifying the volume raycasting code, changing it from an integrator into a segmentizer. Assume that you want to use the threshold method.

You typical volume rasterizer works like this (usually implemented in a shader):

```
vec4 output;
for(vec3 pos = start
   ; length(pos - start) <= length(end - start)
   ; pos += voxel_grid_increment ){
      vec4 t = texture3D(voxeldata, pos);
      /* integrate t into output  */
}
```

The integration step merges the incoming color and opacity of the texture voxel t into the output color+opacitcy. There are several methods to do this.

You'd change this into a shader that simply stops that loop at a given cutoff threshold and emits the position of that voxel:

```
vec3 output;
for(vec3 pos = start
   ; length(pos - start) <= length(end - start)
   ; pos += voxel_grid_increment ){
      float t = texture3D(voxeldata, pos).r;
      if( t > threshold ){
          output = pos;
          break;
      }
}
```

The result of that would be a picture encoding the determined voxel position in its pixels RGB values. Use a 16 bit per channel texture format (or single precision of half precision float) and you've got enough resolution to address withing the limits of what typical GPUs can address in a 3D texture.

You'll want to do this off-screen using a FBO.

Another viable approach is taking the regular voxel raycaster and at the threshold position modify the depth value output for the particular fragment. The drawback of this method is, that depth output modification trashes performance, so you'll not want to do this if framerates matter. The benefit of this method would be, that you then in fact *could* use `glReadPixels` on the depth buffer and `gluUnProject` the depth value at where your moust pointer is.

---

> My thought is as follows:
>
> use gluUnproject function to get two points when I have the mouse
>      clicked on the screen. One point is on the near clip plane and 
>      another is on the far one. concatenate the two points to form a 
>      line.
>      iterate points on the line of step 2 and use glReadPixels to get
>      the pixel value of the iterated points. If the the values jump from
>      zero to nonzero or jump from nonzero to zero(the pixel value of
>      background is zero), the surface points are found.

That's not going to work. For the simple reason that `glReadPixels` sees exactly the same as you see. You can not "select" the depth at which `glReadPixels` read the pixels, because there's no depth in the picture left. `glReadPixels` just sees what you see: A flat image as it's shown in the window. You'll have to iterate over the voxel data, but you can't do this post-hoc. You'll have to implement or modify a volume raterizer to extract the information you need.

Answer (score -1):

I am not going to write here a full implementation of what you need.Also,you could just search the web and [find quite alot](http://martindevans.me/game-development/2015/02/27/Drawing-Stuff-On-Other-Stuff-With-Deferred-Screenspace-Decals/) of info on this subject.But what you are looking for is called ["Decals"](https://bartwronski.com/2015/03/12/fixing-screen-space-deferred-decals/).Nvidia also presented a technique called ["Texture bombing"](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch20.html).In the nutshell,you draw a planar (or enclosing volume)geometry to project the decal texture onto it.The actual process is a little bit more complex as you can see from the examples.

Comment: How are decals supposed to solve OPs problem here? The problem is not drawing something. The problem is, that the dataset OP has does not have "surfaces" at all. It's about as solid as fog. Where would you place the surface of a cloud of fog? OPs problem is, that a volume rasterizer is used to draw fog to the framebuffer, and then OP tries to determine "where the fog" begins based solely on the contents of the framebuffer contents. That's impossible. What OP needs is a segmentation method that decides "fog starts here" and outputs that into the framebuffer to read back.